# How to run local python 3.5/3.6 package downloaded and unzipped from Github on Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I have uploaded the unzipped python 3 package `larch` locally on our server from the school. But I can not either locally installed it by using `pip`, or know how to use the codes from the package folder. Under the main folder `larch-master`, there is a `bin` folder and a file `larch` within the bin.

All the other related codes are saved at `larch-master/py`. Is there any way for me to use the local packages on this Linux server?

After `cd ~/larch-master`
I did `python setup.py install`

and I got the following error

```
checking filemod time on sqlite/sqlite3.c  vs  build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/larch/larchsqlite.so
checking filemod time on sqlite/haversine.c  vs  build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/larch/larchsqlite.so
checking filemod time on sqlite/bonus.c  vs  build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/larch/larchsqlite.so
yes need to update
temp_folder(basepath)= build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
shlib_folder(basepath)= build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/larch
 In file included from sqlite/bonus.c:134:0:
 sqlite/bonus.c:727:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘c’
int isblank(char c){
              ^
sqlite/bonus.c:727:5: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
int isblank(char c){
 ^
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

`File"/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
      File "/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
    % (cmd, exit_status))
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 186, in 
    build_sqlite(buildbase)
  File "~/larch-master/setup_sqlite.py", line 367, in build_sqlite
    objects = c.compile(source, extra_preargs=extra_preargs, debug=DEBUG, macros=local_macros, output_dir=temp_folder(basepath))
  File "/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/gpfs/software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: You should have a `setup.py` file, did you run it? `python setup.py install`

Comment: Hi i just tried to change path to the larch-master, and run python setup.py install, and I got the above errors.